# How to save inputs from Django forms?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-forms, google-cloud-datastore

I have a very entry level question but I could figure it out... My question is how to save inputs created by Django forms to a database (like google datastore)? It seems like there is no .save or .put functions associated with forms. Can anyone give me some suggestions or point out some examples?

Thanks!

Here is the Django forms and the website is hosted by Google app engine.

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='settings'
from django import forms
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class KabamInp(forms.Form):
    chemical_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea (attrs={'cols': 20, 'rows': 2}))
    Koc = forms.FloatField(label=mark_safe('K<sub>OC</sub> (mL/g OC)'),initial=25000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a Model class for the Form and use the values you get from the form to create your entity.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean I should create a models.Model class to build entity and then use save function?

Comment: My further question is if I create this models.Model class, how does it inherit info. from the forms.Form class? Thanks!

Comment: The reason of choosing forms.Form is because its label function is better than model's verbose name

Comment: there are different ways to put the info from the post arguments to your model class. you can do it manually or pass the whole key, value mapping to your model class and put it then. you have to read the docs about the datastore and the model class.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the sample of [Google App Engine Djnago Guest Book](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django-guestbook/)
It will guide thru creating a model/view/controller (MVC) application using Django on the App Engine.

Comment: Thank for the example. I am trying to compare my case vs the Guest Book one.